# how to draw $|x-2|$ with tikz？

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-.5:3]
\draw[->](-.2,0)--(3.2,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->](0,-2.5)--(0,1.2) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[color=blue] plot(\x,abs(2-\x)) node[left] {$y=|x-2|$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It's not correct.

I try to draw two lines `2-x` and `x-2` in different domain. But I fail.

Similarly, how to draw `f(x)=1 (x>0)`, `f(x)=0` else these piecewise functions?

Comment: You're missing a `{}` on the `y` coordinate of the `plot` operation: the last `\draw` should be `\draw[color=blue] plot(\x,{abs(2-\x)}) node[left] {$y=|x-2|$};`

Comment: You can use `pgfplots` for this.

Comment: `\draw[color=blue] (-.5,2.5)--(2,0)--(3,1);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plot is incorrect because the number of samples taken to draw the function is little. Take a large number of samples or use a different domain that allows `x=2`, **TikZ** plot path operation and **Pgfplots** takes 25 samples by default. Here a solution using Pgfplots:

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            domain = -.5:3,
            samples = 50,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            ticks = none
            ]
            \addplot[blue] {abs(x-2)} [yshift=3pt] node[pos=.95,left] {$y=|x-2|$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Applying the solution of KevinC's comment and `plot[samples=50]` can modify your idea to graph the function correctly.

Similarly, you can use different `addplot` with different domains to plot piecewise functions, as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis x line = center,
        axis y line = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        ymax = 2,
        ticks = none
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-3:0,blue] {0};
        \addplot[domain=0.01:4,blue] {1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Additionally, if you want to change the axis label position to outside of the axis, just add this options to the axis environment options:

```
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}
```

Comment: You can also do `samples at={-.5,2,3}` which only evaluates three points to draw this plot.